# Firefox 30 not recognizing font

Tags: firefox, fonts

I am using stylish to change the look of my firefox. I have the font HaxrCorp S8 installed and works in programs such as bblean and sublime text, but when I try to use it in FireFox it doesn't seem to recognizes it and uses sans-serif instead.

I am the changing the font like this:

> font-family: "HaxrCorp S8" !important;

And the fonts are in my fonts folder:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHOQC.png

I've tried adding standard to it but with no success.

Comment: What type is the font? (Like Microsoft OpenType, Apple Advanced Technology, OpenType PostScript, TrueType)? Does it work with another font of the same type? And given bbLean, am I right to assume this is Windows? Which Windows? (And as an aside: Firefox is written with just one uppercase F.)

Comment: @Arjan Aha my bad! I am using windows 8.1. It is a .fon font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Mozilla support forum topic: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/937826, Firefox no longer supports bitmap fonts.