# Why does firefox not use Consolas font while fc-match consolas shows it?

Tags: firefox, fonts, arch-linux, fontconfig

Visiting a pages that use the Consolas monospace font (e.g. [1], minimal example at [3]) instead renders Nimbus Mono.

I installed the Microsoft fonts according to the arch wiki[1] using the ttf-ms-win8 package and font files from a windows 8.1 install on the same machine. Chromium correctly uses Consolas, while Firefox didn't change.

Using fc-match, I get the following results:

```
fc-match consolas
  consola.ttf: "Consolas" "Regular"
fc-match Courier
  n022003l.pfb: "Nimbus Mono" "Regular"
fc-match 'Consolas,"Liberation Mono",Menlo,Courier,monospace'
  consola.ttf: "Consolas" "Regular"
```

The third example is the font-family line from the site's css. I assume firefox doesn't just pass this to fc-match, but short of reading the code, I am out of ideas.

*The question is*: Why doesn't firefox use the consolas font when specified?

---

Software versions:

- Chromium 48.0.2564.103
- Firefox 44.0
- fontconfig 2.11.1-2
- Arch testing

Notes

- [4] is a similar question, but consolas is a truetype font, so the quoted fact that firefox doesn't support bitmap fonts isn't relevant here.

References

1. https://github.com/necolas/idiomatic-css
2. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Microsoft_fonts
3. http://absolute.fail/consolas_problem.html
4. [Firefox 30 not recognizing font](https://superuser.com/questions/788522/firefox-30-not-recognizing-font)

Comment: Works on Windows 7 64-bit, Firefox 44.0.2 64-bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for quite some time and GitHub was a pain to watch. I finally installed [fontconfig-ttf-ms-fonts](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/fontconfig-ttf-ms-fonts/) today and problem solved!

Comment: Now it uses Courier new. This is better and seems to work because fontconfig-ttf-ms-fonts specifies that "courier" means "courier new". But consolas already matches, so this doesn't solve my problem.